# How do I install the Grace plotting tool on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, installation

Could someone write an easy-to-understand, step-by-step guide on how to install [Grace](http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Grace/) (the WYSIWYG 2D plotting tool) on Windows 7 64-bit?  I've read a lot and I still don't understand how to install it.

Comment: Please post the exact problem and how far you got.

Comment: From a quick read, you'll need something like Xming installed before you can even think about getting Grace working.

Answer (score 1):

From the [README.packages](ftp://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/pub/grace/README.packages) file on the [Grace FTP server](ftp://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/pub/grace/):

> Win9*/NT/2k/XP:
>
> Grace package is now a part of the Cygwin (http://cygwin.com/) distro.
>
> http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=grace/grace

Comment: You'll also probably need an xserver like Xming installed.

Answer (score 1):

There also is a windows version called qtgrace: http://sourceforge.net/projects/qtgrace/

Just unzip and launch bin/qtgrace.exe

It uses grace (console version) as a backend. Xmgrace is the wysiwyg version on linux side that also uses grace as a backend. Qtgrace is a native windows application that uses QT in similar fashion than Xmgrace uses X and motif.